# My code works in Python 3.8, but the same code does not work in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses, python-class

my code works perfectly in Python 3.8, but when I switch to Python 3.5 in same operating system, with same code and everything else, it starts throwing out "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Here is the error, and the part of the code that I think which relates to the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pwb.py", line 390, in <module>
    if not main():
  File "pwb.py", line 385, in main
    file_package)
  File "pwb.py", line 100, in run_python_file
    exec(compile(source, filename, 'exec', dont_inherit=True),
  File ".\scripts\signbot.py", line 83
    namespace: int
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
CRITICAL: Exiting due to uncaught exception <class 'SyntaxError'>
```

And here is the part of the code :

```
@dataclass
class RevisionInfo:
    namespace: int
    title: str
    type: str
    bot: bool
    comment: str
    user: str
    oldRevision: Optional[int]
    newRevision: int
    timestamp: int
```

Sorry if the question title is not specific, but I'm having troubles getting this code working in Python 3.5. The server I'm going to run this code in only supports Python 3.5, so I need to get this working with 3.5. Thanks.

Comment: So... have you looked at the release notes for Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8 to see what the main changes were in each of them? Have you tried using other versions of Python to narrow down the specific version where this starts to work?

Comment: If you NEED it to work with minimal refactoring, maybe take a look at [attrs](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues here:

1. [Variable annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep526) were new in Python 3.6.
2. The [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=dataclass#module-dataclasses) module was new in Python 3.7.

Either use Python 3.7 or greater, or rewrite your code so it doesn't rely on dataclasses and variable annotations.

This is one of many reasons that it's a good idea to use the same version of Python in development as you intend to use in production. You can avoid writing code that won't work on your server.

Comment: Beyond dataclasses, 3.5 only supported annotating function parameters (PEP 484), 3.6 added support for variables (PEP 526). That's why there is a syntax error and not just an import error, the interpreter doesn't even reach the stage of failing to import `dataclasses`.

Comment: @Masklinn, you're right, and there was another answer (and comment) saying the same. But it looks like its author deleted it for some reason. I'll roll that into my answer.

Answer (score -1):

One new and exciting feature coming in Python 3.7 is the data class. you're not able to use it in python 3.5.
You should use the traditional way and use constructor:

```
class Mapping:
def __init__(self, iterable):
    self.items_list = []
    self.__update(iterable)

def update(self, iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        self.items_list.append(item)
```

Comment: "coming in Python 3.7"? Python 3.7 was released over two years ago, in June 2018, and Python _3.9_ is about to come out.

Comment: "Data classes are one of the new features of Python 3.7. With data classes, you do not have to write boilerplate code to get proper initialization, representation, and comparisons for your objects."
https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/#:~:text=Data%20classes%20are%20one%20of,fields%20in%20your%20data%20class @chris

Comment: I know that, but your answer makes it sound like this is a brand new feature that hasn't even been released yet. In fact, it has been in the stable release of Python for 26 months or so.

Comment: (For what it's worth, I didn't downvote your answer.)